# AngularJS Routing not working with Spring MVC web app

Tags: angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc, routes, ngroute

I'm trying to use angularjs routing to load my templates and am getting a `'404 page not found error'` no matter what templateurl I put down. Should I be changing my `context.xml` file or am I just missing a step here? Any input would be appreciated.

This is my routing config (app.js):

```
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/mainview',
            controller: 'appController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
   });
```

=============================

And my Spring Controller is as follows (SampleController.java):

```
    @Controller
    public class SampleController {

        @RequestMapping(value="views/mainview", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String displayView(){
           return "views/mainview.jsp";
        }
     }
```

=============================

Folder structure is as Follows

> - java
>
>   - com
>
>     - sample
>
>       - controller
>
>         - SampleController.java
> - webapp
>
>   - META-INF
>   - resources
>
>     - js
>
>       - app.js
>   - WEB-INF
>
>     - views
>
>       - mainview.jsp

Answer (score 0):

templateUrl property defines which HTML template AngularJS should load and display inside the div with the ngView directive. 
Use 
templateUrl : 'mainview.html'

Comment: So then I shouldn't worry about the Spring Controller? I've tried so many combinations of the path for templateUrl and still getting a page not found error?

Comment: Correct this @RequestMapping(value="views/mainview", metohd=RequestMethod.GET) in your code, you have written "method" as "metohd" @angularjs newbie

Comment: Try to return only "mainview" from your controller's method.

Comment: Tried that. Should I be changing web.xml? Or should it just work with my angularjs routing config?

Comment: Can't you post your all files

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the server where the server is serving file

for example : 
java/com/views/mainview.html
or
views/mainview.html

Comment: I edited the structured of my folders in the question. My app.js file is located in `webapp/resources/js/app.js` and my template is located in `webapp/WEB-INF/view/mainview.html`. Would it still just be `views/mainview.html`? I've tried it and still getting the same error.